# How can I edit a jpg image through Java?

Tags: java, image, netbeans

I have loaded a jpg image in which I want to draw letters and circles, given a x,y coordinate.

I have been trying to figure out the paintIcon of the [ImageIcon](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html) class

```
public void paintIcon(Component c,
                      Graphics g,
                      int x,
                      int y)
```

Does this method allow me to edit jpg images the way I want to? What are supposd to be the Component c and Graphics g paramethers? What would I add to its body to paint circles or letters?

I'm working on Netbeans 6.5, do I have anything builtin for this task (instead of ImageIcon)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The pure-Java way is to use [`ImageIO`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) to [load](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read(java.io.File)) the image as a [`BufferedImage`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html). Then you can call [`createGraphics()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#createGraphics()) to get a `Graphics2D` object; you can then draw whatever you want onto the image.

You can use an `ImageIcon` embedded in a `JLabel` to do the displaying, and you can add a `MouseListener` and/or a `MouseMotionListener` to the `JLabel` if you're trying to allow the user to edit the image.

Answer (score 14):

Manipulating images in Java can be achieved by using the [`Graphics`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) or [`Graphics2D`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) contexts.

Loading images such as JPEG and PNG can be performed by using the [`ImageIO`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) class. The `ImageIO.read` method takes in a `File` to read in and returns a [`BufferedImage`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html), which can be used to manipulate the image via its [`Graphics2D`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) (or the [`Graphics`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html), its superclass) context.

The `Graphics2D` context can be used to perform many image drawing and manipulation tasks. For information and examples, the [Trail: 2D Graphics](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/2d/index.html) of [The Java Tutorials](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/index.html) would be a very good start.

Following is a simplified example (untested) which will open a JPEG file, and draw some circles and lines (exceptions are ignored):

```
// Open a JPEG file, load into a BufferedImage.
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("image.jpg"));

// Obtain the Graphics2D context associated with the BufferedImage.
Graphics2D g = img.createGraphics();

// Draw on the BufferedImage via the graphics context.
int x = 10;
int y = 10;
int width = 10;
int height = 10;
g.drawOval(x, y, width, height);

g.drawLine(0, 0, 50, 50);

// Clean up -- dispose the graphics context that was created.
g.dispose();
```

The above code will open an JPEG image, and draw an oval and a line. Once these operations are performed to manipulate the image, the `BufferedImage` can be handled like any other `Image`, as it is a subclass of `Image`.

For example, by creating an [`ImageIcon`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html) using the `BufferedImage`, one can embed the image into a [`JButton`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html) or [`JLabel`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html):

```
JLabel l = new JLabel("Label with image", new ImageIcon(img));
JButton b = new JButton("Button with image", new ImageIcon(img));
```

The `JLabel` and `JButton` both have constructors which take in an `ImageIcon`, so that can be an easy way to add an image to a Swing component.

Answer (score 5):

Use a library to do just that. One that you might try is [JMagick](http://www.jmagick.org/).

Answer (score 2):

I have used Java Advanced Imaging library ([http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jaifaq.html](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/jai-142803.html)), but you can also look at ImageJ (http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

I imagen you could use this method to overlay the elements you need every time the image is drawn in the UI (this would happen numerous times as you are not drawing ON the image data its self) but may be suitable to your purposes (and advantageous if the overlay changes over time).

Something like:

```
new ImageIcon("someUrl.png"){
    public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
        super(c, g, x, y);
        g.translate(x, y);

        g.drawOval(0, 0, 10, 10);
        ...

        g.translate(-x, -y);
    }
};
```

Having said that, mmyers' answer is much better if you want to modify the image data.