# How do I remove lines from a picture with Java?

Tags: java, image-processing, line

I have multiple images that look like a table with border:
[image: this]

I want to remove the surrounding lines (framing boxes) on it so they look like a table without border
[image: this]

Is there any way to do this through code with Java?

Comment: Use morphology with long line just shorter than the cell dimensions. Sorry, I do not know the Java interface to Imagemagick.

Comment: This question is multiple questions in one. It's unclear if you are looking for an algorithm to detect the unwanted lines, or if you just don't understand how to do pixel manipulation in Java. Are the forms always like this, or may there be other kinds of forms? Why do you want to keep some lines, and how do you distinguish these?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, I want to detect any lines longer than x pixels and remove them.

Answer (score 0):

The pure-Java way is in this thread:
[How can I edit a jpg image through Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009607/how-can-i-edit-a-jpg-image-through-java)
If you know the coordinates (or approximate coordinates) of each line, you can draw white lines over the black ones (white rectangles if you only know the approximate coordinates).

Comment: Not a good solution. It needs to be automated. I do not think he can rely upon measuring the endpoints of each line in every image

Comment: "know the coordinates" is an assumption. You should clarify "if" they do know in a comment otherwise propose __how to apply your linked solution here__, e.g. how to approximate the coordinates. Then how to draw the lines. Maybe with some pseudo code. This would improve your hypothetical answer :)